# Delete Mails from Postfix Queue with filter from and to

Tags: regex, grep, postfix-mta

I try to delete some special mails from Postifx Queue.
I want to Filter with "Mail From" and Mail Domain "TO".

I have tried:

```
mailq|grep 'info@sendingdomain.com'|awk '/ @test\.com$/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d -
```

But it don't work.

Comment: With mailq | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / test@test\.com/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d - I can delete one mail with To: but how to include FROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this bunch of code

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -n "$1" ] && echo "Usage : $0 mail" && exit 1

for mail in $( mailq|egrep '^[A-Z0-9]'|grep "$1"|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/^\([0-9A-Z]*\).*$/\1/' )
do
    /usr/sbin/postsuper -d $mail
done
```